# How can I turn React Testing Library "not wrapped in act" warnings into Jest unit tests errors

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

We are unit testing our react app using Jest and React Testing Library. And we get some of this "classic" errors :

```
console.error
      Warning: A suspended resource finished loading inside a test, but the event was not wrapped in act(...).
      
      When testing, code that resolves suspended data should be wrapped into act(...):
      
      act(() => {
        /* finish loading suspended data */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

But some Some developers simply ignore the error of this type. So, as time passes, the tests output is bloated with warning like that. And our tests feel less confident.

Is there a config in Jest or in React Testing Library that turns this kind of warning in error and makes the unit tests fail ?
I search in Google and found a lot of (good) articles to solve the warning but not to turn it into real error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jest-fail-on-console]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fail-on-console npm package to make the tests fail on console.error, console.warning.